# How to find and return the index of the increasingly lowest value in an array Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, indexing

I have an array `{ 8, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 7 }` which I want it to return the index of the lowest value in an array, the index of the next lowest value in the array and so on.

I have this code;

```
private static int getSlotPosition(int[] iArray) {
        int lowestValue;
        lowestValue = iArray[0];
        int slot = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < iArray.length; i++) {
            if (iArray[i] < lowestValue) {
                lowestValue = iArray[i];
                slot = i;
            }

        }
        return slot;

    }
```

The above method is being called in a for-loop, changing the arrangement of the array every time it is called.

So I want the output (that is, the index) to be returned after every call to the method (assuming the positions remain the same) to be like;

1. Index returned after first call is 6, cos 1 is the lowest value
2. Index returned after second call is 3, cos 2 is the next lowest value
3. Index returned after second call is 2, cos 3 is the next lowest value and so on

Please could someone help me out. Thanks.

Comment: You have no way to specify which "lowest" you want; every time you call this method you will get "1".

Comment: Hello @ElliottFrisch, thank you for your comment, maybe I can pass a second parameter into the method and use that to always determine the index of the lowest increasing value, but how do I then achieve that?

Comment: Will your array have duplicate values, and what is the range of the values in the array?  You can remove elements from a List.

Comment: No, the array would not have duplicate values. The size of the array can change based on the array being passed into this method.

Answer (score 0):

Your method returns an int which means it cannot return anything other ONE value. If you want solve the task, you need to do it with recursion, or make the method return an array with the lowest indexes in order.

Comment: Yes, I want it to always return one value, the index of the lowest value after this method is called the first time, the index of the next lowest value after this method is called the second time and so on.

Comment: Then you have to remove the value from the array when its returned. You simply cannot pass a method the same arguments and get a different answer. If you really want to do this with only one method call you have to do it with recursion, but that is not something for beginners

Comment: I would not want to delete the value whose index I have gotten each time. Do you know how I’m to go about it with recursion?

Comment: No as reccursion can be quite difficult. And seeing the questions you are asking makes me think you should work more on mastering the basics. Just do remember, you cannot get a different output from a method if you give it the same input.